# I don't know what formula to do

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I want a function that checks what is in the 'deck choice' column (F). And then store the wins, loses and draws of that 'deck'. So for example:

The 'TES' deck would have `10` wins, `6` loses and `1` draw. I want the three pieces of information to be displayed like the total values to the right of the table.

[The spreadsheet in question.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10KIo6lBSR3hCEl0mPQzNKyG0JTmIR9MamkISrphsiLk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @pnuts Excel's formulas behave almost the same as Google-Spreadsheet's, and I'm here only because of those tags, so I think they are useful.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set?  The outcome is clear but we would need to see how the data is organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only one certiria so `SUMIF` will do..

Lets say your selection is on J12.

for Total Wins:

```
=SUMIF(F:F,J12,G:G)
```

For Total Loses:

```
=SUMIF(F:F,J12,H:H)
```

For Total Draws:

```
=SUMIF(F:F,J12,I:I)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `SUMIFS` formula. E.g:

```
=SUMIFS(G$2:G$9, $F$2:$F$9, "=TES")
```

[Your spreadsheet updated](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Stq1G11Bclur2fywQiI0uo0Xg0t8F8AEvkD7zx9K5UM/edit?usp=sharing).